# Making value-type arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, mono, value-type

I'm transfering data between c++ and c# and I really need to have value-type arrays or list to pass the data directly. I don't mind them being a const expression. Is there a way to have an array which would behave like a c# struct or like a c++ std::array?

Edit: In the worst case i can use std::vector but i would prefer std::array because i really care about performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about arrays of primitive types (`byte`, `int`, etc.) then marshalling between C# and C++ is quite simple using `fixed`:

```
        unsafe
        {
            byte[] arr = new byte[1024];
            fixed (byte* nativeArray = arr)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)nativeArray;
                // Pass ptr directly to C++ and use as an unsigned char*
            }
        }
```

Note this requires use of the `unsafe` option when compiling.

The same works for `int`, `uint`, `short`, `ushort`, `float`, `double`, `long`, and `ulong`.

You **MUST** use the pointer on the C++ side immediately and either copy it to a native buffer or be done with it before returning. The point of `fixed` is to make sure the memory isn't GC'd or moved while control is inside the `fixed` block.

Comment: Why bother and not just rely on normal marshalling, which does exactly the same thing for arrays of unmanaged valuetypes?

Comment: @Charlieface It's not clear to me from the documentation whether the default marshalling behavior for a primitive array is copying or pinning. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning.  Assuming it's pinning then yes it's the same, though I think it never hurts to know how to do these sorts of things explicitly.

Comment: From that page: "Formatted blittable classes have fixed layout (formatted) and common data representation in both managed and unmanaged memory. When these types require marshalling, a pointer to the object in the heap is passed to the callee directly. The callee can change the contents of the memory location being referenced by the pointer." so yes it's pinning for any valuetype which can be marshalled without changing any of the data, such as numeral types and `bool`

Comment: @Charlieface ah yes ok. It's actually clarified in a linked article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types - "One-dimensional arrays of blittable primitive types, such as an array of integers. However, a type that contains a variable array of blittable types is not itself blittable.". That was the part I wasn't sure of but good for all to know.

Comment: Yes, arrays themselves are blittable, but the references are not (because the reference is to a C# object whereas the pointer woud be to the first value, which is after the header) so classes or structs containing arrays are not blittable.